# Is there a way to start a file with my PowerShell compiled script per double click?

Tags: powershell

I have created a PowerShell script and then compiled it with PS2EXE. The program loads *.JSON-files and allows the user to edit it. The program starts with a file browser window to select the right *.JSON to load.

Now I want to try to run the program by double-click a *.JSON and skip the file browser window.
So I right klick the file > select open with > and choose mypowershellapp.exe and inspected the `$PWD` var. But it was always the system32 directory.

So: How to get the file path the program was started from?

Comment: *How* did you compile a PowerShell script? Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed: when you use File Explorer's `Open with...` shortcut menu and select an application to pass the document at hand to, that application invariably launches with `C:\Windows\SYSTEM32` as its working directory.

However, the document at hand is passed *as an argument* by its *full* path, so you can *infer* the directory it is located in.

That is, in your (compiled) `*.ps1` script, do something like the following:

```
# Note: 
#  * Use of $args[0] assumes that your script declares no formal parameters.
#  * Adjust as needed.
# $args[0] is the document's full *file* path.
# Split-Path -Parent extracts the *directory* path from it.
$dir = Split-Path -Parent $args[0]
```

Of course, you can also pass this directory to `Set-Location` to change the application's working directory.

Comment: Thanks, that's nice. I have now this code: `try {
 $startdir = Split-Path -Parent $args[0]
 write-host "You have choosen $startdir."
} catch {
 write-host "No file loaded, please choose one."
 #dialog
}`

The problem is that I get a folder path but not a file path. Is it possible to change it?

Comment: @jjb, `$args[0]` by itself is the full path of the JSON _file_ that was acted on in File Explorer.

Comment: Thanks! It works, my fault .